# How to match a character from a text file?

Tags: bash, sed

I have delimited text file containing the following:

```
jen|Y|Y|N|Y|jen.com,shop.jen.com,help.jen.com%W
billy|N|N|N|Y|billy.com,files.billy.com,office.billy.com
john|Y|N|N|Y|john.com,blog.john.com,home.john.com%W
```

How would I check if each line contains a `%W`? So I can use it in a if statement to perform a function.

This is what I have tried so far but no luck because the file contains pipes as well to separate the fields.

```
while IFS="," read -r Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5 Field6 Field7 Field8; do
if [[ $F8 ==%W" ]]; then
    ______________________________
fi
done <"$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bash:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
if [[ $line == *"%W"* ]]; then
  echo "%W is on this line: $line"
fi
done < "$1"
```

See [this Bash demo](https://ideone.com/NemGgF).

The `if [[ $line == *"%W"* ]];` part checks if a `line` contains `%W` anywhere on the line. It is a glob wildcard pattern, not a regex, where `*` matches any zero or more chars.

If the `%W` should only be checked at the end of a line, remove the `*` on the right.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just wondering if you can assist on another question I have - In the text file the first 5 fields are separated by pipes  and the rest are separated commas, how would I get it to read the fields separated by commas? 

This is what I have to read from the fields separated by pipes so far:
`Username=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f1)`
`FTP_flag=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f2)`
`DNS_flag=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f3)`
`SMB_flag=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f4)`
`NFS_flag=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f5)`

Comment: @carlos88 I think the `Domains`  part must be `Domains=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f6)`. Or what should `Domains` hold? See https://ideone.com/6y26h6

Comment: Yeah the domains are -f6 but there are 3 of them all separated by commas `jen.com,shop.jen.com,help.jen.com` how would I make them separate?

Comment: @carlos88 But they are already separate if you split with comma. What is your intent? If you want to keep the items in a `Domains` variable, you can just keep it as is. If you want to iterate through the values later split the commas with space, `Domains="${Domains//,/ }"`

Comment: Yes very close, what I am trying to do is make two directories for each domain like this https://ideone.com/KMqjFM but it is giving me a error "Cannot create directory" when I test with your code in CentOS. Can you tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: @carlos88 If you create a directory in the current one, why do you use `/project2/$Username...`? Remove the first `/`. Also, it has nothing to do with the current question already, please consider accepting the answer that worked best for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226013/discussion-between-carlos88-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

Merely checking whether all lines contain `%W` is probably best done with `grep`.  The following will print those which lack it, with a line number.

```sh
grep -vn '%W' file
```

If you want to split on multiple delimiters and do additional processing inside a loop, perhaps try

```sh
awk -F ',' '{ split(/\|/, a, $1);
    # Now | -delimited fields are in a[1], ...a[6], rest are $2 $3 $4
}
!/%W/ {print a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], $2, $3, $4 }' file
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just wondering if you can assist on another question I have - In the text file the first 5 fields are separated by pipes and the rest are separated commas, how would I get it to read the fields separated by commas? This is what I have to read from the fields separated by pipes so far: 
`Username=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f1)` 
`FTP_flag=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f2) `
`DNS_flag=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f3) `
`SMB_flag=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f4) `
`NFS_flag=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f5)`

Comment: The Awk code above does exactly that. Your shell attempt would work but as you see it's repetitive and painful. A more elegant - albeit more obscure - solution might involve `set` with a custom `IFS='|'`